# what is meant by completeness of Hilbert space?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, mathematical-physics

I know definition that  completeness means  every Cauchy sequence of elements of the space converges to an element in the space.But what does it mean physically when we say Hilbert space is complete inner product space ? ( specially when we talk about quantum physical system associated with Hilbert space)